# How To Move Node-Red Project

Tags: node.js, node-red

I have a node-red project that was working fine. I back'ed up the .node-red folder and have now reinstalled ubuntu and node-red on the same computer. I'm using      the node-red-contrib-postgrestor node to access PostgreSQL. After installing all the required nodes and copying the flows.json and settings.js files to the .node-red folder, I **cannot** get the flow to authenicate with the PostgresSQL database. I've edited the node properties and re-entered the user name / password info and re-deployed. I've tried changing the credentialSecret property in the settings.js file to a new secret string plus I've tried changing the property to false. The flows_cred.json file is either: (1) not created, (2) it is created with contents "{}", or (3) it is created with encrypted data. In none of the cases can I get the node to authenticate with the database.  I tried putting debugging statements in the postgrestor.js file and it shows that the user name and password are "undefined".

```
function PostgrestorNode(config) {
const node = this;
RED.nodes.createNode(node, config);

node.topic = config.topic;
node.config = RED.nodes.getNode(config.postgresDB);
node.on('input', (msg) => {
  node.warn(`user: ${node.config.user}, password: ${node.config.password}`);

  const query = mustache.render(config.query, {msg});
  const pool = new Pool({
    user: node.config.user,
    password: node.config.password,
    host: node.config.host,
    port: node.config.port,
    database: node.config.database,
    ssl: node.config.ssl,
    max: node.config.max,
    min: node.config.min,
    idleTimeoutMillis: node.config.idle
  });
```

Originally the node-red program was working in Ubuntu 16.04. I upgraded to 18.04 when the problem occurred. I've since gone back and reinstalled 16.04 thinking that was the problem, but it doesn't work either way now.

I have read the following:

https://github.com/node-red/node-red/wiki/Design%3A-Encryption-of-credentials

The last sentence "Note that once you set credentialSecret you cannot change its value." is maybe my problem, but surely there's got to be a way to change the logon credentials for the database.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

---

I have now discovered that the node-red-contrib-postgres node does not experience the connection problem with the database. There must be a specific issue with the node-red-contrib-postgrestor node.

Comment: Is your problem fixed ?

Comment: I switched to using node-red-contrib-postgres-multi and that fixed my problem.
https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-postgres-multi
This component also handles errors without terminating the flow which solved another problem I was having.

Comment: That is good news.  Maybe it would be good to describe this in an answer below and mark the answer as accepted so this would make clear that this stackoverflow question is closed.